# node.js sass / scss parser to output json

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, sass

Is there any SCSS / SASS parser for Node.js ?

Of course, there is the [original one](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/85e96bc36dcc2b9d7a5b0815e2b274669f701850/lib/sass/engine.rb), written in Ruby.
Could it be used to output json (and just use the json in node) ?

I just want to get the rule tree in JSON to work with it in Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [node-sass](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass). it wraps libsass and is pretty fast.

Not sure if you can use its api to get the JSON representation of the parsed SCSS though...